# How is it possible that queueable apex jobs run for multiple hours and can not be aborted

Tags: apex, job

Last week we had an issue with a queueable jobs which ran for more than 8 hours and thereby locking many records during this period. We were not able to abort this job and were obliged to sit it out.
We do not expect a code issue since this code has been used successfully for a long time.
Are there any known issues that could explain our problem or is it just something random.

Comment: This is not possible, it may be a cyclic queueable operation. Even queueable has a limit for 60 seconds.

Comment: It probably shouldn't be possible although the job had the status processing for 8 hours until it failed.